# Error with Connection String in MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to retrieve data from an SQL Server database table in my MVC application. I have the following connection string:

```
<add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SampleHR;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

But this gives me the following error:

Cannot open database "SampleHR" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

On this line in my ActionResult code:

```
Employee empPersonal = epcontext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeID == eid);
```

I tried the following two connection string:

```
<!-- <add name="Employee_PersonalContext" connectionString ="server=MANASI-HP\MSSQLSERVER; database=SampleHR; integrated security=SSPI;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> -->



<!-- <add name="Employee_PersonalContext" connectionString ="server=MANASI-HP\MSSQLSERVER; database=SampleHR; username=dbo; password=;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> -->
```

But these two gave me the error: "The underlying provider failed to open."

I have SQL Server 2012, with Windows Authentication. I ran the query "select CURRENT_USER" and got the username "dbo". I have not set any password and I am using Windows Authentication. I am also running the application on IIS server.

What could be the problem? Please let me know if I have to add any code here.

Edit: I went to project properties and changed the server to SQL Server instead of IIS and it works with this connection string:

```
<add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SampleHR;Integrated Security=True;User ID=IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool;Password="
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

but not with this one:

```
<add name="MvcDemoConnectionString" connectionString="Server=MANASI-HP;Database=SampleHR;Integrated Security=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I am confused.. :(

Edit 2 (11th Nov): I did not make any changes to IIS Manager right before I started with the MVC application in .NET. Just followed the instructions in the tutorial. I found this page about IIS.

[IIS Data Source Settings](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-3-configure-data-source-settings)

Do I need to do any of these things before I start building my application on IIS?

Dec 5th 2015:
I followed the instructions on these two pages:
[ASP.NET Web Deployment](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis)
and
[Deploy Database with IIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465343(v=vs.100).aspx)

Still not working.

Comment: Have you had any luck with any of the responses below?

Comment: No. I don't get where exactly I have to make changes / settings: SQL Server, IIS or Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to grant the user permissions in SSMS. I just went back to default settings in ISS, granted permission to the user in SSMS, and that was it. 
Does anyone have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the app in IIS and your connection string uses integrated security, the user it is going to use is whatever the app pool is running as. You can either change the user the app pool is running as, or provide the username and password for the windows authentication user you want to use in your connection string (something like `Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SampleHR;Integrated Security=True;User ID=username;Password=password`

Comment: I've never seen this proven to work (providing windows user name in the connection string) but I would be interested in any documentation that it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have hosted application in IIS and allow anonymous access, and your connecting string accepting windows authenticated user.

Whenever you have this type of setting in place, I'll recommend to run IIS application pool under service account instead of AppPoolIdentity, and make sure your SQL Server allow service account user.

For testing go to Application Pool -> advance settings -> and change 'Identity' with you network/windows credential. if your account have access to sql server your problem will be solve for a moment.

Note: I'll not recommend to keep running your application under personal account. Because once you change your password you have to change the App pool Identity again.

Comment: In the Application Pool, it shows me three options: .NETv4.5, .NETv4.5 Classic and DefaultAppPool.  I clicked on DefaultAppPool -> Advanced Settings --> Identity. This showed me a form with two options: 1) Built-In Account --> this had four options in drop-down box: LocalService, Local System, NetworkService and ApplicationPoolIdentity (this is selected)      2)Custom Account : I clicked on Set button and it gave me a form to set credentials -> UserName and Password.    Is this where I have to make a change?

Comment: I tried creating a Custom Account with my Account name and password, but it says Invalid Password. What kind of password is it asking for?

Comment: First you have to check which application pool your application is using. You can do this checking Basic Setting of your application in IIS. For setting up service account you have to use 'Custom Account'

Answer (score 0):

If you don't change, each app pool has it's own identity. In your case, just add a new user to your database SampleHR with the name IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool using SQL Management Studio. You find the users list in the "Security/Users" subnode of your database.

Comment: In creating a new user, I specified UserName = IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool,  Login Name = ManasiHP-Manasi. What should be the Default Schema? Can I select anyone from the list?  Also, should the UserName be "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool, as it is throwing the error? Or will I have to create an entity in IIS with the same name too?

Comment: Create User failed because the UserName contained invalid characters... I tried removing the space in the name, but the same error happened. I tried just the user names "MyAppPool" and "DefaultAppPool". Then the error said,"The login already has an account under a different user name."